# Regex that allows only one + sign at the beginning and then numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to match regex to allow it to start with + (only one plus) sign at the beginning and then to allow only numbers.

Here is my directive:

```
(function(app) {
    'use strict';

    var plusOnly = function() {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
                function inputValue(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        var digitsPlus = value.replace(/^\+[0-9]+/g, '');

                        if (digitsPlus !== value) {
                            ctrl.$setViewValue(digitsPlus);
                            ctrl.$render();
                        }
                        return parseInt(digitsPlus, 10);
                    }
                    return undefined;
                }
                ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
            }
        };
    };

    app.directive('plusOnly', [plusOnly]);

})(angular.module('App'));
```

HTML:

```
<input class="input" type="text" only-digits-with-plus="" ng-model="phone">
```

Although this limits to numbers and + it still allows me to have multiple pluses.

Where am I making the mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: So you are replacing for example `+1234as+asdf` with `as+asdf`? Is that what you expect?

Comment: No, I want this format exactly: `+numbers`. Like `+43434`, nothing else. First + sign then numbers, Only limit 1 plus sign, and only in the first position. Then numbers.

Comment: Just add the end anchor: `/^\+[0-9]+$/`. To make the plus optional, add a `?`: `/^\+?[0-9]+$/`

Answer (score 4):

You just need to limit + to only one, like this:

```
^\+[0-9]+$
```

test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/GjBr07/1)

**EDIT:**

since you're having problems with logic of your code... if I understood you correctly, you want to remove everything except things matched by your regex. In fact, you want opposite of `regex.Match`. In that case, you need negative lookahead, like this:

first, check if input is valid, and then, if it is, replace values...

```
var match = value.match(/^\+[0-9]+$/g);
if (match !== null) {
    //now replace values using negative lookahead...
    var digitsPlus = value.replace(/^(?!\+[0-9]+)$/g, '');
    //some other code
```

That could be the answer to your issues.

Comment: This doesn't allow + in the first position.. I believe the error is in my directive somewhere..

Comment: @stormec56 Are you sure? this allows exactly one + followed by 0 or more numbers. I have edited my answer with test

Comment: It still allows multiple + in between.: https://regex101.com/r/Vevt3V/2

Comment: @stormec56 in that case, add $ to the end of regex. Answer edited.

Comment: Please see @Sergejs answer bellow. Still not working well.. Could the error be in my directive logic?

Comment: @stormec56 ok, now i get it. Edited my answer once again :)

Comment: Your code is not working, mate

'+++123dfds'.replace(/^(?!\+{1}[0-9]+)$/g, '');
"+++123dfds"

Comment: Please check this @Nino

Comment: @stormec56 i suggested a solution with `match` and then `replace`. have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression is correct.

You have a logic problem in your function.

You are taking the input value, (whatever it is) and you are replacing in the input value +12321(any numbers) with an empty string, for example:

+43432abc you are replacing to abc.

But you should do vice versa.

I would suggest to do something like this:

```
var digitsPlus = value.replace(/^.*?([\+0-9]?[0-9]+)?.*?$/, '$1');
```

Comment: Please write what exactly should I do. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to do something like this:
var digitsPlus = value.replace(/^.*?([\+0-9]?[0-9]+)?.*?$/, '$1');

Comment: What are you talking about?

"123" turns into  "123"

"+123" turns into "+123"

"++123" turns into an empty string ""

Comment: I know, tested and working fine.. but not in my project. Looks like something is blocking it.. Could it be parseInt in the directive? input type as well?

Comment: Yes, try to return digitsPlus; instead of parseInt(digitsPlus, 10);

Comment: Nope.. not accepting plus sign. My full directive: https://jsfiddle.net/v0e8nbgj/

Comment: Make a working jsfiddle, otherwise it does not help.